# Low Graphics Mode- NVIDIA. No way to desktop

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics, windows-7, asus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Ive been looking around here and seen many variations of this error but none that have helped me. Starting up gets me to a window telling me "the system is running low graphics mode" clicking OK gets me to a menu of four options, like reconfigure, troubleshoot, and exit to console login. These are all varying degrees of unhelpful.

CRT-alt-F1 gets me to text login, and 
Sudo lspci
TellS me I have (for VGA compatible controller) NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce G210M] (rev a2).

I'm on an Asus laptop with an intel duo core. Somewhere else I found how to update my drivers, but they are all up to date. Any help appreciated.

(I don't know if this goes without saying, but when I was testing it out from a CD Ubuntu worked fine. It's only now that I've installed it alongside W7 that his is occurring).

Answer (score 1):

once i had luck with installing "gdm" and setting it as the default display manager.  i don't know why it worked with gdm and not with lightdm.  but it worked.

for it,  you have get to the cli and give 'sudo apt-get install gdm' , (while connected to internet) , give your password and select gdm as default display manager.

to connect to internet from cli, you can use ' sudo pppoeconf and give your ethernet details or you can use a wireless hotspot, which you have previously connected,   using the already used hotspot is much easy,  as it would most probably connect automatically.